# Should I declare variables as close as possible to the scope where they will be used?

Tags: c#, variables, scope

*ReSharper* usually suggests me that, and I'm still looking for a good reason of why to do that.

The only thing that came to my mind is that declaring it closer to the scope it will be used, can avoid initializing it in some cases where it isn't necessary (because a condition, etc.)

Something related with that is the following:

```
int temp;
foreach (var x in collection) { 
    temp = x.GetValue();
    //Do something with temp
}
```

Is that really different than

```
foreach (var x in collection) {
    int temp = x.GetValue();
    //...
}
```

I mean, isn't the second code more expensive because it is allocating memory everytime? Or are both the same? Of course, after finished the loop, in the second code the garbage collector will take care about `temp` variable, but not in the first one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cost of the second example is negligible. The only difference is that in the first example, `temp` will be available outside the scope of the `for` loop, and thus it will exist longer than if you declared it inside the `for` loop.

If you don't *need* `temp` outside the `for` loop, it shouldn't be declared outside that loop. Like others have said, readability and style are more at play here than performance and memory.

Comment: So there isn't any performance difference between those two codes? (it is an `int`, but it could be a more complex class that will require more space in memory...)

Comment: @Oscar - Stack variables are essentially free apart from a minimal initialization cost.

Comment: The compiler may move variables declared within the loop outside of the loop anyway, so no, there really isn't any performance difference. You gain readability and maintainability by declaring them at the beginning of the scope in which you need them.

Comment: @Oscar - Even if it's a more complex object all you're doing is copying a reference.  Not a big cost.

Answer (score 7):

Declaring as close as possible to use is a readability decision. Your example doesn't display it, but in longer methods it's hard to sift through the code to find the temp variable.

It's also a refactoring advantage. Declaring closer to source leads to easier refactoring later.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that if you init a variable inside the scope that it's being used then you're helping the gc out, but I think the real reason is more to do with code maintenance best practices.  It's sort of a way of reducing cognitive load on you or another developer coming back to the code after months (or years) of not looking at a particular block.  Sure, IDE's help you discover things, but you still have to do the "go to definition" dance.

Comment: Agreed. Hopefully that will be one of the best reasons `:)`

Comment: I wanted to clarify why it can reduce the cognitive load in case anyone was curious. Other developers will not have to think as much about where else `temp` is being used. It helps give context to that variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance benefits, I believe, but more of a coding style. Its more C programming style to declare it all at the beginning of the scope. There is more details here: [Scope of variables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979493/scope-of-variables-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Its a style personal preference thing to do with readability.

There are very few languages/systems where this will have any noticeable effect on performance.

I try to follow these two rules.

All the core attributes of a class should be defined together in one place. e.g. If you are handling an order then orderno, customerno, amount, sales tax etc. should be defined close together.

All the technical attributes which form part of the internal mechanics of the class such as iterators, flags, state varaibles should be defined close to thier usage.

Or to put it another business/external type data all defined in one place, technical/internal data defined close to usage.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is a matter of coding style and one of such dispute that different coding standards have completely opposite rules.  The conflict is still strongest in the C++ world where the C language forced variables to be declared at the beginning of a scope and so old-timers (like myself) were well accustomed to "looking at the beginning of the function" to find variables.

The C# style that you most often see is that variables come into existence right at the point where they are needed.  This style limits the existence of the variable and minimizes the chance that you could mean some other variable accidentally.  I find it very easy to read.

In the modern C# era, putting the declaration of variables at their first point of use is most clearly beneficial when combined with the both loved and hated `var` feature.  Using `var` *just isn't that useful* unless you use it with an assignment that allows the compiler and readers to infer the type of the variable.  The `var` feature *encourages* declaration with first use.

Me, I love `var`, and so you can guess which coding style I prefer!

Answer (score -2):

I was always taught to declare your variables at the top of a function, class, etc.  This makes it easier to read.

Comment: What language were you using then?

Comment: Professors have sinned