# C# variable declaring

Tags: c#, variables, declaration

Is there any practical difference (speed, memory) between these two ways of declaring (introducing) variables? Which one is the better way?

Example 1:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Length; i++)
{
    MyObject m = myObjects[i];
}
```

Example 2:

```
MyObject m = null;

for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Length; i++)
{
    m = myObjects[i];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to use object inside for loop only its good to have it in for only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop

Comment: Sorry, I should searched the previous questions more. This seems to be already answered in an earlier case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1 makes it so that `m` is only "alive", in memory, within the scope of the for loop.

Example 2 makes it so that `m` stays occupying memory after the for loop finishes executing.

I would go with example 1, this is why:
[Declaring variables inside or outside of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop) (I won't really tell you, in detail, to force you to read the link.)

Answer (score 1):

`Performance-wise` both are compiled to the same IL, so there's no difference.

The first one is better because you are meaning to have a new object in each iteration. Also there is no need to have an object if the loop condition fails

Comment: Why do you believe that they compile to the same IL?