# TypeScript using const in reference to block scoped

Tags: typescript

In terms of functionality the options 1) and 2) achieve the same result. And I guess the Typescript compiler translate those options into the same Javascript code. Or at least the Javascript interpreter does, if Typescript compiler does not do this optimization. I was used to declare variables **not** inside a loop to avoid re-declaration, which becomes interesting for objects with non-trivial constructor. Because the constructor and destructor is called for every iteration in option 1). But option 2 comes up with following reasons (nowadays) also for more complex objects:

- no accessible outside of the loop
- indicates it will not be reassigned
- some people find it more concise and easier to read

What is best practice declaring variables (let/const) with respect to the scope?

1)

```
let someVar = "";
this.array.forEach(item => {
  someVar = item;
  // no further reassignment of someVar
  ...
});
```

2. 

```
this.array.forEach(item => {
  const someVar = item;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you meant by "best"? And how big is this array and how big is each item? Are you looking to repeatedly generate js, or just one-and-done during start-up?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, scoping has little (none, as far as I know in this case) to do with TypeScript compilation and more to do with JavaScript itself. You can read what TypeScript adds to JavaScript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html), but it has more to do with typing and less to do with variable declaration. You may be referring to the compilation of JavaScript to a lower-level language, but I wasn't sure what you meant.

In my opinion, only use case 1 (declaring with 'let' outside of the loop) if you need to access the variable after the loop. If you don't need to do this (i.e. if you only ever need to access the variable within each individual iteration of the loop), then declare it with `const` in the loop (case 2).

You could also use `let` (case 1) if you only update/set the value of the variable on *some* iterations of the loop but want to read the value as updated by previous iterations of the loop in most or all iterations.

Comment: "You may be referring to the compilation ..." I mean that your TypeScript is optimized by compiling to JavaScript. And during this process, I expected the compiler creates the same JavaScript code in both options, because he "knows" the functional results are equal.

Comment: TypeScript makes a point of not modifying the output JavaScript. It only strips types; and does some basic transformations if requested, mainly related to module loading. And enums...

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Typescript, I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "it will translate both options into the same code".
The two examples are completely different code so these 2 resulting in the same code wouldn't make any sense.

In terms of readability, if you declare something outside of the `forEach` I would guess that it's being used somewhere else later. It might lead to some confusion. If the outer scope doesn't have a need for the variable just keep it locally to the callback.

---

**EDIT**: I provide some more information since I understood your issue more when I read your comments.

Typescript doesn't care about analyzing the runtime of your code. This job is out of its scope. Typescript all it does is provide you with this special syntax for types on top of Javascript. The compiler then does the type checking and then outputs javascript code again.
Then usually the code will pass to a bundler where you could do some optimizations such as dead code elimination, from unused variables to unused modules.
But you won't see from these building tools an optimization that changes the runtime execution.
Sure you could definitely try to do such modifications in the runtime code with a tool but why would you do that?
It's like building a tool to optimize your code before sending it to the compiler which itself will handle all the optimizations. Why a type checking tool, a transpiler or a bundler bother to do it?

Such optimizations sure will happen, but from the JS engine itself.

You can actually try compile your examples with the Typescript compiler and see for yourself what's happening. Typescript has also an online playground in which you can experiment:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: "In terms of Typescript, I'm not sure..." It mean that I guess that the Typescript compiler performs something similar to other like gcc (any sort of data flow analysis), and can figure out that the variable it's not being modified outside the loop. So it should produce the same optimized code in both cases. Or if not Typescript does, the JavaScript interpreter does.

Comment: @Hölderlin TypeScript won't do that. It really just converts the 'Types' that it adds to javascript back into JavaScript. It doesn't really modify anything in native JavaScript.
If you're really wondering about how to best declare variables, then this isn't a TypeScript question at all. It's a JavaScript question (or maybe even just a general functional programming question).

Comment: @arkatsy in your `reduce` the variables are still being re-declared when they are passed as local variables to the `reduce` callback.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica You're right, I totally missed that. Thanks for correcting me. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> In terms of functionality the options 1) and 2) achieve the same result. And I guess the Typescript compiler translate those options into the same Javascript code. Or at least the Javascript interpreter does, if Typescript compiler does not do this optimization.

Option 1) and 2) are not the same code, neither in TS nor JS.

> I was used to declare variables **not** inside a loop to avoid re-declaration, which becomes interesting for objects with non-trivial constructor. Because the constructor and destructor is called for every iteration in option 1).

There is no desctructor in TS/JS, objects get destroyed and cleaned up by the Garbage Collector. If you are interfecing with native modules (C or C++) then you'd usually have a public `dispose` method to do the necessary cleanup (or let the C++ destructor do its job).

Let's get back to your question. JavaScript is an interpreted language, meaning that there usually isn't a compilation step that would generate the necessary code to deal with pushing and popping variables to and from the stack. That happens at runtime, on-demand.

In both your options, the `item` variable is pushed to the stack to make it available in the `forEach` callback, so it is **always** being redeclared for **each item** in the array. That makes this statement invalid `I was used to declare variables **not** inside a loop to avoid re-declaration`.

Now, an interpreted language can be very slow compared to a compiled one. For this reason, some very smart people came up with some optimisation techniques to speed up the interpreted nature of the language. One such technique is called Just-in-Time (JIT) compilation, meaning that if the runtime detects that a certain piece of code is called multiple times, it can compile it down to more optimal code and use that instead of re-interpreting the code again and again.

Going back to your code examples, in option 1) JIT could be fooled that it cannot do an optimisation of the loop because it has external references. While for option 2), it knows that all needed references are inside the loop and it can go ahead and optimise it completely. So, technically, option 2 is more "correct" because it uses the scopes as they are intended: use a variable at the most `local` scope possible, rather than poluting the outer scope for no reason.

Comment: You are correct; I did not use the term "compile" precisely enough. Nowadays, there are static compilers for [JavaScript](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/138541) or [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1326084/7096274). The point is that Java, which is also an interpreted language from some perspectives (sharing similar concepts with JavaScript, such as Garbage Collection, etc.), has a [rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21956888/7096274), in contrast to C++, to declare the object outside the loop as well, and you are always on the optimal side.

Comment: This aligns with what I learned years ago. Perhaps things have changed now, or maybe they are different, especially for JavaScript? However, at the moment, I do not believe that this is true.

Comment: @Hölderlin I guess it also depends on the scenario at hand. If you have some JS code that needs to be super performant then it would make sense to compile it to webassembly code to squeeze some of that performance. Or maybe the bottleneck is the memory and some objects re-use could do the job. It really depends on use-case.