# How can I get my program to print out each character as "Character #1: (character) , Character #2: (character), etc"?

Tags: java, loops

```
int i;

System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
String string_1 = input.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Entered string: " + string_1);

  for ( i = 0;  i < string_1.length();  i++ ) {
     System.out.println ("Character #1:" + string_1.charAt(i));
  }
```

How can I get the program to print out each character on new line headed by "Character #(the characters number):"

Sorry if the question is confusing, I'm new to programming

Comment: You're very close. One important thing you missed was instantiation of the object `input` for reading text from the console, e.g. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 1):

You can print "i" as text

```
 System.out.println ("Character #" + i + ":" + string_1.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are only printing `"Character #1:"` in each loop iteration.  Instead of that, you'll need to output `"Character #"`, then `(i + 1)`, then `":"`, then `string_1.charAt(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here. First of all, you are never actually creating an object to accept input from the console. In Java, this task is often carried out using a `Scanner`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Next, typical Java code conventions (taking [Google's guide for example](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html)) dictate that variable names should be in camelCase style, and should not contain underscore characters. A better name for `string_1` would therefore be `input`, or something similar.

```
System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
String input = sc.nextLine(); // input from console
System.out.println("Entered string: " + input);
```

Finally, in your `for-loop`, you want to increment the number that is being displayed to the user for the character location as the loop progresses. This is done by concatenating a `String` that includes the loop variable `i`. Since the loop is zero-indexed, and presumably you want the output to be interpreted by humans, it would be useful to add one to the index when displaying it.

```
for (int i = 0;  i < input.length();  i++ ) {
    // build a string using `i + 1` to display character index
    System.out.println ("Character #" + (i + 1) + ": " + input.charAt(i));
}
```

It's also worth noting, that declaring the loop variable `int i` within the loop definition is preferable, as it limits the scope of the variable (See: [Declaring variables inside or outside of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop)).