# Why can I create multiple instances with the same name in a loop?

Tags: java, object, for-loop

I don't understand why this works and I hope somebody can explain it to me.
Here is an example:

```
TestObject array[] = new TestObject[10];
for(int i= 0; i <= 10; i++){
    TestObject object = new TestObject();

     object.setValue(i);
     array[i] = object;
    System.out.println(array[i].getObject());
}
```

Why can I create multiple instances of "TestObject" with the same name in the loop?
Usually you can't create instances with the same name:

```
TestObject o = new TestObject(1);
TestObject o = new TestObject(2);
```

Well, this will obviously throws an error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring variables inside or outside of a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop)

Answer (score 3):

The scope for a `for` loop is limited to the iteration. So `TestObject object` is created and destroyed in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
But I save every instance of TestObject in a global Array. Do they still have the same name in the array?

Comment: You're not actually storing the objects' names. You're storing the objects' references. If you look inside the array, you'll see an array of unique objects with unique references.

Answer (score 3):

Every iteration of a loop is a block and, as a block, has its own scope. You can achieve the same result by doing this:

```
{
    int i = 0;
}
{
    int i = 1;
}
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because 'object' is in visibility scope of current loop iteration, so for next iteration, there can be initialized a new one with the same name (other scope).

Answer (score 0):

it's the scope of object problem. every iteration has its scope let's say they are not the same object at all