# Declaring/initializing variables inside or outside of a double (or multiple) loop

Tags: java, optimization, performance-testing, nested-loops, micro-optimization

According to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop), and multiple Google searches, declaring or initializing a variable outside or inside a loop "might" be the same in terms of performance.

I am running a computer simulation, and I am trying to optimize the code as much as possible, because it has to run a lot of times and it has multiple inner loops with a lot of iterations.

I am wondering if it worth moving all my variables outside of the loops. I have many variables that "theoretically" are constantly re-declared. I said "theoretically" because I don't know if the the Java compiler actually optimize the code and declare everything at, let's say, the method level.

Basically, what would be more efficient? CodeA or CodeB?

Code A:

```
private void codeA() {
    double a = 0.0;

    for (int i1 = 0; i < i1_N; i1++ ) {
        // Many other loops
             for (int im = 0; i < im_N; im++ ) {
                 a = 0; // a is used for the first time
                 for (int in = 0; i < in_N; in++ ) {
                     a++; // calculate something with a
                 }
             }
        // close many other loops
    }
}
```

Code B:

```
private void codeA() {
    double a;

    for (int i1 = 0; i < i1_N; i1++ ) {
        // Many other loops
             for (int im = 0; i < im_N; im++ ) {
                 a = 0; // a is used for the first time
                 for (int in = 0; i < in_N; in++ ) {
                     a++; // calculate something with a
                 }
             }
        // close many other loops
    }
}
```

Code C:

```
private void codeC() {

    for (int i1 = 0; i < i1_N; i1++ ) {
        // Many other loops
             for (int im = 0; i < im_N; im++ ) {
                 double a = 0; // a is used for the first time
                 for (int in = 0; i < in_N; in++ ) {
                     a++; // calculate something with a
                 }
             }
        // close many other loops
    }
}
```

I am just using the variable a in this example, but the computer simulation uses much more. Most of my variables are primitives (int, double, float). Does it make sense to declare primitives outside of the loop in order to improve performance?

Comment: So you got your test case, why not simply run the test? My suggestion is that (as long as you do not use objects), the results will pretty much stay the same. What really eats time are constructor calls. If you use objects, you might want to recycle as much as possible.

Comment: You have the code ready, why don't you check the runtimes for, say, 1000000 calls of each function. If differences are big, you'll notice, won't you?

Comment: Don't forget to read this: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103)

Comment: Thanks but I haven't implement the version with variables declared outside the loops. I am asking to see if somebody can hint if I should try to optimize.

Comment: If there is something to improve in that example, then HotSpot ([Oracle article about JIT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm)) could do that probably better than you. You should try to write clear code, which means, reduce the scope of variables, if possible. (Repost to fix the link)

Comment: @bl3e Nah, ideone is not a Java microbenchmark, it's just for running the code once - it's a different beast :)

Comment: Perhaps you can start another SO question regarding the bechmarks. This has very little relevance, if any, with my original question. I need a hint if I should try to implement the optimization to save the time programing a new version of my simulation. I might try the benchmarks after I decide to implement that version. I need information to decide.

Comment: @toto_tico There is only one way: measure. But to be honest I would be *extremely* surprise if it made a difference at all.

Comment: @toto_tico Right, sorry for that. I thought such question may be closed as "asking for a tool/library" or "primary opinion-based". But, in the meantime I'm setting up JMH locally to test your thing, so I may have an answer for you in a while. (It takes more than 5 minutes to me though:))

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk My bad.I missed later part of the comment.compilr looks to be sort of an online ide(I haven't tried).Btw did you mean a website which could generate jmh tests and produce results?

Comment: @bl3e Yes, exactly. You just paste the code like OP has given and go. Maybe tweak some benchmark parameters after the test (but the default one should be reasonable for most of the cases).

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk, Coda A and B are different just by the initialization, which I don't know how does it work in Java for primitives (I have this clearer for Objects). All that I know is that in Java you cannot use (compile) a variable that hasn't be initialized, so there might be a difference. I stopped assuming anything with modern compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javac` will not optimize. Bytecode generated in all the 3 cases [is different](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/e943966785be551585f4#file-bytecode). (`javac Test.java` compiles and `javap -c Test.class` shows the bytecode)

Java Virtual Machine may optimize.

[JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark shows the clear winner:

```
Benchmark           Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testA  thrpt   20  423.437 ±  6.745  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testB  thrpt   20  337.728 ± 56.363  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testC  thrpt   20  351.419 ± 70.290  ops/s
```

Units are operations per second, the more the better. [Benchmark source code](https://gist.github.com/AdamStelmaszczyk/e943966785be551585f4#file-mybenchmark-java). OpenJDK IcedTea 2.5.4 Java Virtual Machine was used.

So, declaring and initializing variables outside should be the most efficient.