# Object creation rate

Tags: java

A very basic question:

```
//List<Students> b;
for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
  List<Students> b = school.getstudents(classID);
}
```

Although it is recommended to keep the scoping as small as possible,is there any advantage of a outer scope variable  when we are looping through a possibly unbounded counter.
Is there any difference in  the instances created and promoted from the young generation by either of the approaches?
To be more specific, in case we are looping through a count on a million students - would we be reducing the possibility of higher object promotions and full GC if we declared the variable outside

Comment: Are you talking about hoisting *just* the variable out of the loop, or also the call to `school.getstudents()`?

Comment: Why... why would you fetch the same value over and over again? What's the point of this loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring variables inside or outside of a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop)

Comment: Repeated variable declaration should be optimized by the compiler. Repeated variable initialization can't be avoided without changing the algorithm itself.

Comment: To be more specific, in case we are looping through a count on a million students - would we be reducing the possibility of higher object promotions and full GC if we declared the variable outside

Comment: The way you create the reference has nothing to do with garbage collection.