# Fill an new array with elements of array A that are missing form array B - Java

Tags: java, arrays

So, basically i have two Arrays:

```
int[] listA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10};
int[] listB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};
```

and I want to fill in a new array (`listD`) all elements of `listA` that are missing from `listB`.

The output should be like this:

Output: 2, -5, -121, 102, -35, 0, -125, 802, -10

My code is the following:

```
int arraySize = 0; //Variable to determine size of the new array;
int difElements = 0; //Variable to count every different element;

for(int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < listB.length; j++){
        if(listA[i] != listB[j]){
            difElements++;
        }
        if(difElements == listB.length){
        arraySize++;
    }

    }
     difElements = 0;
}
System.out.println("Size of the array with different elements : " + arraySize);

int[] listD = new int [arraySize]; //Declaring array with specified size;
```

I then use the following for loop to run trough both arrays and check if there are repeated elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < listB.length; j++) {
        if (listA[i] != listB[j]) {
            listD[i] = listA[i];
        } else {
            listD[i] = listA[i + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

I know what's wrong with the loop, using Debugger it's quite easy to see where it goes wrong, but at this point i'm just running in circles and coding the same mistakes... After the loop finds the repeated element i can't find a way to normalize the condition (`listD[i] = listA[i]`) since it has skipped a postion. Maybe I need another loop just to iterate trough listD but I've never nested three loops before...

Bare in mind this is really basic java programming, these are just exercises from my class to get the basics of java programming. I have no knowledge of any POO, classes, methods etc etc and can't apply them of course.

Comment: I think, you have used wrong word instead "missing" should be "except"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use one temporary array (say `listC`) to store the positions of the elements that we need to copy.

Iterating through both arrays for the first time, you calculate the size of the new array *and* set flags if the elements are unique.

Then you iterate through the `listC` and copy the unique elements from `listA`

```
int[] listA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10, 7, 555};
int[] listB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2, 7, 555};

// array of flags indicating which elements of listA to copy
int[] listC = new int[listA.length];

// counter of unique elements from listA
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++) {
    boolean contains = false;
    //simplified form of for loop if you don't use an index
    for (int b: listB) {
        if (listA[i] == b) {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!contains) {
        counter++;
        //setting listC[i] to 1 if listA[i] is not present in listB
        listC[i] = 1;
    }
}

// declaring array with specified size 
int[] listD = new int[counter];

counter = 0;

// iterating through the array of flags to copy unique elements
for (int i = 0; i < listC.length; i++) {
    if (listC[i] == 1) {
        listD[counter++] = listA[i];
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listD));
```

Comment: wow, so simple! Thank you so much mate :) Just a quick question, when using an boolean like this, why did you declare and put it under the for loop? couldn't you declare it before the for loop as false, and only use the condition "contains = true" aftwerwards?

Comment: @Rui I was glad to help! I put `boolean contains = false;` inside the `for (int i = 0; i < listA.length; i++)` loop because I need to check this condition for each element of `listA`. If I declared it outside the loop, I would have to assign it to `false` at each iteration anyway. However, [the scope of local variables should always be the smallest possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803806/8629960). There is also a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8878071/8629960)

Comment: Ok, understood it completely! Thanks a bunch mate :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use java 8 you can use this.

```
List<Integer> aList = Arrays.stream(listA).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> bList = Arrays.stream(listB).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

aList.removeIf(o -> bList.contains(o));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a marker something of `boolean` type to identify

1. Element that is in listA and not in listB.
2. Duplicate not found for adding to new list.

Now the code starts with three `arrays` one `listA`, `listB`, `listC`. `listC` can only have size same as `listA`, because that's the maximum (worst case that no elements of `listA` match with `listB`). Plus I'm adding my markers

```
int[] listA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10, 0, 2};
int[] listB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};
int[] listC = new int[listA.length];
boolean elementFound = true;
boolean duplicateFound = false;
int thirdArrayIndex = 0;
int zeroCount = 0;
```

We will come to markers `elementFound` and `duplicateFound` later. First we will do the basic nested iteration

```
for(int i=0; i< listA.length; i++) {
    boolean elementFound = true;
    for(int j=0; j< listB.length; j++) {
```

Asking to iterate `listB` with each element of `listA`. Now inside the loop for `listB` we keep a code for checking similarity of elements and setting the unique element mark.

```
if(listA[i] == listB[j]) {
    elementFound = false;
    break;
}
```

If element in `listA` matches with `listB` keep `elementFound` as false and break the inner loop because no need to search again. That takes the execution to outer loop where we will check whether `elementFound`. If it is true then only proceed to add the element.

The adding part will be like this

```
if(elementFound) {
    boolean duplicateFound = false;
    for(int k=0; k< listC.length; k++) {
        if((listA[i] == listC[k]) || (listA[i] == 0 && ++zeroCount > 1)) {
            duplicateFound = true;
            break;
        }
     }
     if(!duplicateFound) {
         listC[thirdArrayIndex++] = listA[i];
     }
}
```

Before the next for loop starts we will keep `duplicateFound` as `false`. Inside for loop we will check two conditions

1. Whether element not in `listA` is already present in `listC`.
2. The initial `listC` will be having all elements initialized with `0`. So even if `listA` is having element as `0` and which is not present in `listB`, it won't be added to `listC` because `0` is already present according to condition-1.

That's why the condition is like `if((listA[i] == listC[k]) || (listA[i] == 0 && ++zeroCount > 1))`. Initially value of `zeroCount` is `0`, so when a `0` is found in `listA` not in `listB`

```
listA[i] == 0 --> true &&
++zeroCount(value = 1) >= 2 --> false
```

So the first `0` in `listA` will be added. After the for loop with `k` is over or either `breaked` we will check not condition of `duplicateFound`, ie no duplicate found in `listC`, if that's true the go and add element of `listA` to `listC`

```
listC[thirdArrayIndex++] = listA[i]; // listC[0] = listA[i]; first time
```

Only after the execution of this line the value of `thirdArrayIndex` will be incremented refer [How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java).

Now when for loop with `i` is finished all the elements in `listA` not matching with `listB` will be added to `listC`, but if matching elements are found not all `listA` elements will be added to `listC`, so rest of the `listC` elements will be having value `0`. That's why we will use a fourth array `listD` to copy only the elements from `listC` that were added from `listA`.

That's where `thirdArrayIndex` have its significance, by now `thirdArrayIndex` means the total number of elements added from `listA` to `listC`. So the last part of the code will be like

```
int[] listD = new int[thirdArrayIndex];
for(int i=0; i<listD.length; i++) {
    listD[i] = listC[i];
}
```

Finally print all the arrays

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listA));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listB));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listC));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listD));
```

So final program will be like

```
int[] listA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10, 0, 2};
int[] listB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};
int[] listC = new int[listA.length];                
int thirdArrayIndex = 0;
int zeroCount = 0;

for(int i=0; i< listA.length; i++) {
    boolean elementFound = true;
    for(int j=0; j< listB.length; j++) {
        if(listA[i] == listB[j]) {
            elementFound = false;
            break;
        }
    }           
    if(elementFound) {
        boolean duplicateFound = false;
        for(int k=0; k< listC.length; k++) {
            if((listA[i] == listC[k]) || (listA[i] == 0 && ++zeroCount > 1)) {
                duplicateFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicateFound) {
            listC[thirdArrayIndex++] = listA[i];
        }
    }
}
int[] listD = new int[thirdArrayIndex];
for(int i=0; i<listD.length; i++) {
    listD[i] = listC[i];
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listA));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listB));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listC));
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(listD));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all elements of listB to a HashSet hashSet, then iterate through each element of listA and check if the element is in the hashSet using hashSet.contains().  If it returns false, then add to listD.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

```
int[] listA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10};
int[] listB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};

List<Integer> b = Arrays.stream(listB).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Integer> d = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i: listA) {
    if (!b.contains(i)) {
        d.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but i was looking for an answer without using any methods for the java API, but loops and conditions. is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do without using list, it's better to maintain a `boolean` array to mark a elements of `listA` true if it is in `listB` and `k` gives us no of similar elements between `listA` and `listB`. So the resultant array will be of size `listA.length-k` and you can simply add elements after that

```
int[] listA = {2, -5, -121, 102, -35, -2, 0, -125, 802, -10};
int[] listB = {6, 99, -1, 12, 1, -2};

int k=0;
boolean isInB[] = new boolean[listA.length];

for(int i=0;i<listA.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<listB.length;j++){
        if(listA[i] == listB[j]){
            isInB[i] = true;
            k++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int[] listResult = new int[listA.length-k];
int r=0;

for(int i=0;i<listA.length;i++){
    if(isInB[i] == false){
        listResult[r] = listA[i];
        r++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the same idea as in my answer. But you seem to do some  
redundant iterations in your nested loop - if `listA[i] == listB[j]` you do not need to iterate through `listB` anymore.

Comment: @KirillSimonov yup we can break out from the loop

Answer (score 0):

Let me give my 5 cents.

I agree, that this problem could be solved with plain old `Java` or using `streams`. But I think, that you do not think about element duplication, that could be important. E.g. `listA = 2,2,2` and `listB = 2,2`. So I think, that one `2` is missing, so it should be in output.

I give you my approach, it works with this situation and with unique elements as well. I do not use `streams` to be simple and clear, but you could minimize it using `streams`:

```
private static int[] missing(int[] listA, int[] listB) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int val : listB)
        map.put(val, map.getOrDefault(val, 0) + 1);

    int total = 0;

    for (int val : listA) {
        int count = map.getOrDefault(val, 0) - 1;
        map.put(val, count);

        if (count < 0)
            total++;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int[] listD = new int[total];

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        if (entry.getValue() < 0)
            for (int j = entry.getValue(); j < 0; j++)
                listD[i++] = entry.getKey();

    return listD;
}
```