# Class Design Quality

Tags: c#, class

Is this class written by me is sufficient (I mean the way the pro's do it) to be included in a code/project? Or am I missing important things? I don't know how to use constructors etc so I did not use the same (I m just a beginner in C#) but please comment if so are required.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace RandBit
{
    /// <summary>
    /// By: Author
    /// Version 0.0.1
    /// Pseudo-Random 16-Bit (Max) Generator.
    /// </summary>
    public class RandomBit
    {
        /// <param name="input">The Bit-size(int)</param>
        /// <returns>Random Bit of Bit-size(string)</returns>
        public static string Generate(int input)
        {
            int bitSize = 0;
            Random choice = new Random();
            if (input == 0 || input > 16)
            {
                bitSize = 0;
            }
            else if (input == 1)
            {
                bitSize = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                int randomChoice = choice.Next(0, (1 << input));
                bitSize = randomChoice;
            }
            string binary = Convert.ToString(bitSize, 2);
            binary = binary.PadLeft(input, '0');
            return binary;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using `Random` incorrectly. I'd suggest starting with [Jon Skeet's article on the subject](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx). Relevant quote:

> If you start off an instance of Random with the same initial state
>   (which can be provided via a seed) and make the same sequence of
>   method calls on it, you'll get the same results.
>
> So what was wrong in our example code? We were using a new instance of
>   Random on each iteration of the loop. The parameterless constructor
>   for Random takes the current date and time as the seed - and you can
>   generally execute a fair amount of code before the internal timer
>   works out that the current date and time has changed. Therefore we're
>   using the same seed repeatedly - and getting the same results
>   repeatedly.

In other words, since you are creating a new instance of `Random` with each call, you are greatly increasing the chances that the return value won't be as "random" as you would expect.

It's also worth mentioning that there are [potentially better](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) PRNG classes already in the .Net BCL. Here's another way of writing similar code.

```
private static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider _crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

public static long Generate(){
    // use whatever size you want here; bigger has a better chance of 
    // being unique in a given scope
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];

    // puts random bytes into the array
    _crypto.GetBytes( bytes );

    // do something (your choice) with the value...
    return BitConverter.ToInt64( bytes, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. How do I fix that?

Comment: The most important point is to keep a single instance of your RNG, not create new instances repeatedly. I added a sample which shows one way of doing that, and also used a stronger RNG. The article I linked to shows a variety of approaches using both `Random` and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

You may only change one thing, since your class only contains a single static member, why don't make the class as static.

Answer (score 1):

If I were the project team leader I would require that you drop summary/author/version comments. They are redundant (source control has that info), take a some time to write/modify and are ambiguous (in a file modified by 7 people who's the author?).

Here's a discussion on this topic, perhaps not the only one: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/48562/30927

Answer (score 0):

Move the variable "Choice" close to its usage i.e within the else loop.
Otherwise, You will be allocating un necessary memory to Random Object even if not used.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133586/should-i-declare-variables-as-close-as-possible-to-the-scope-where-they-will-be)